# Perl array numbers to hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

In Perl, I have an array

```
my @array = (1 3 6 12);
```

From the above array, I want hash which is mapped from one to next value and continue.

I want this to be output like this. And the last the number should be mapped to its own

```
$VAR1 = {,
          '1'  => '3',
          '3'  => '6',
          '6'  => '12',
          '12' => '12'
        };
```

This is the code I have tried to get the hash from arrays in Perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my @array = qw(1 3 6 12);

my %hash = @array;

print Dumper \%hash;
```

I get the output as:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '6' => '12',
          '1' => '3'
        };
```

Can someone help since I am beginner in Perl ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having?

Comment: Easy enough to do with a for loop. And `$values_hash = ( ... );`? That's not how you create a hash variable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the array directly to the hash to get half of the pairs. Use an array slice to get the other half.

```
my %hash = (@values, @values[1 .. $#values, $#values]);
```

This doesn't work for an array with an odd number of elements, but it's unclear what output you expect in such a case. Also, it's unclear what to do with repeated elements.

Answer (score 5):

The common way to walk an array is to use a `for` loop to iterate over the elements of the array.

```
for (@values) {
  say $_;
}
```

But in this case, we need each element in the array as well as the *next* element in the array. So it'll be more convenient to iterate over the *indexes* of the array. We use the special variable `$#values` which gives us the final index in the array.

```
for (0 .. $#values) {
  say "The value at index $_ is $values[$_]"
}
```

We can then get next element as well:

```
for (0 .. $#values) {
  say "$values[$_] => $values[$_ + 1]"
}
```

Running that gets us close to the data we want:

```
1 => 3
3 => 6
6 => 12
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at array2hash line 10.
12 =>
```

But because 12 is the last element in the array, getting the next element makes no sense (and Perl gives us and `undef` value - hence the warning).

In your example, it looks like you want the final element to point to itself. We can use the "defined-or" operator (`//`) to handle that:

```
for (0 .. $#values) {
  say "$values[$_] => ", $values[$_ + 1] // $values[$_];
}
```

All that remains now is to store the required data in a hash:

```
my %values_hash;
for (0 .. $#values) {
  $values_hash{$values[$_]} =  $values[$_ + 1] // $values[$_];
}
```

Using [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) to examine our hash, we get this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '3' => 6,
          '12' => 12,
          '6' => 12,
          '1' => 3
        };
```

Which (taking account of the fact that hashes are unordered) is what we wanted.

A Perl expert might rewrite it as:

```
my %values_hash = map {
  $values[$_] => $values[$_ + 1] // $values[$_]
} 0 .. $#values;
```

**Update:** Another approach would be to use a hash slice.

```
my %values_hash;
@values_hash{@values} = @values[1 .. $#values, $#values];
```

Comment: This solution doesn't help the OP print the hash in desired output

Comment: @steveo314: I don't understand your comment. The OP's question used Data::Dumper and I've shown the Data::Dumper output from my first example. What was the desired output that I haven't covered?

Comment: They wanted the output to be sorted by key in numerical order

Comment: @steveo314: Well, they don't specifically ask for that. It's true, the output in their question is sorted. But it's also true that the output is clearly from Data::Dumper. And given that hashes are inherently unsorted, that's hard to do. You can use `$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys` of course, but that does a string sort (so 12 sorts before 3).

Comment: When they give the desired output a certain way it usually means they desire the output that way. Data::Dumper doesn't sort the output unless you ask it to you like you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Step through the array and use each element as a key and the next element as the value unless you are at the last element:

```
 foreach $x(0..$#array) {
    ($x == $#array) ? ($hash{$array[$x]} = $array[$x]) : ($hash{$array[$x]} = $array[$x+1]);
 }
 foreach $y (sort {$a<=>$b} keys %hash) {
     print "$y => $hash{$y}\n";
 }
```

Comment: That maps each element to itself - which isn't what the question asked for.